# How to add, calculate and filter those elements that are less than average without using repetitive cycles

Tags: java

I am using the (`List`) java structure:

```
var nums = List.of( 3, 9, 7, 12, 20, 4, 11, 9, 21, 6, 8, 10 );
```

Through that use, I am performing the following program without the need to use repetitive cycles:

```java
    package averagesumwithoutcycles;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.util.List;
    
    public class SumaSinCiclos {
        
        private static int suma = 0;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] nums = {3, 9, 7, 12, 20, 4, 11, 9, 21, 6, 8, 10};
        System.out.println(average(nums, 0));
    }
    
    public static float average(int n[], int pos){
        float resultado = (float)suma /(float)n.length;
        if(pos < n.length) {
            suma = suma + n[pos];
            average(n, pos + 1);
            System.out.println(resultado);
        }
        return resultado;
    }
        
    }
```

So far I have achieved the following:

- Sum of the Array elements
- Number of elements in the Array
- Division Result (Average)

My question is the following, based on my code, how can I sum the elements (`array`), calculate the average, and filter those elements that are less than the average.

Note: It is important to obtain this data without using repetitive cycles

Comment: You mean you don't want to use for and while loops? You are using recursion, which is basically a loop already

Comment: @Mick Seriously? well they mentioned the topic about using list, I shouldn't use repetitive loops like these: `for, while, do while`

Comment: I do not have code for you, but I can suggest sorting an array using recursion and at the same time calculate a position (index) of an average element. Then, you can get a 'lower' part of the array that is before an average index.

Comment: @Mick I thought that by not being one of these `for, while, do while` in the code, I would be complying with that condition of not using repetitive cycles.

Comment: Well technically it's different from an iterative loop, but it's still a recursive loop. Is it a school project or something? I wouldn't recommend using recursion for something like this in a practical application

Comment: @Mick It is a practice, seeing examples I have put together the code exposed in my question, where I have to add the elements, calculate the average and filter those elements that are below the average, where repetitive cycles cannot be used, but rather the use of structures: (list) this is called functional programming is as far as I understand.

Comment: @Mick Can you help me with this: ¿how can I sum the elements (array), calculate the average and filter those elements that are less than the average. I don't think I have a long way to go to achieve what I want, do I?

Comment: I'm not an expert on the subject of functional programming, but I can give you the textbook answer to the question

Comment: @Mick It will be useful, thank you.

Comment: You can't filter on an average without having an average first.  And then to filter, you must use a loop.  I think there is a disconnect on what a repetitive cycle is.  Imho, a cycle is a single loop.  A repetitive cycle would be a nested loop.  In other words, filter once thru and be done.  But that is just a guess.

Comment: @WJS So the repeating cycles are not these: `for, while, do while`

Comment: @WJS In conclusion they can always be used as long as they are in a single use, without being repetitive. But then why was it suggested to use list structures? functional programming.

Comment: @Pepe I don't know what your instructor intended so I can't say for certain.  But to find an average you need to sum up all the elements. You could do it with repetitive sums (each statement).

Comment: @WJS It is that they will not make me work if repetitive cycles are used, so I was hoping to find a solution without using these cycles: `for, while, do while`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the best possible answer in my opinion. It does use loops internally, but any possible solution to get the sum of an array requires a loop (iterative or recursive).

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

class Main {  
    private static int suma = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] nums = {3, 9, 7, 12, 20, 4, 11, 9, 21, 6, 8, 10};
        for (int num : nums) {
            System.out.println(num);
        }
        nums = filter(nums, average(nums));
        System.out.println("____________\n");
        for (int num : nums) {
            System.out.println(num);
        }
    }
    
    public static float average(int[] n){
        float suma = IntStream.of(n).sum();
        return suma / n.length;
    }
    
    public static int[] filter(int[] nums, float average) {
        return Arrays.stream(nums).filter(x -> x >= average).toArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you really think that using streams is appropriate here?

Comment: I think it's the only way without explicitly using a loop or recursion

Comment: @Mick Thanks for the contribution, but the use of for, and repetitive cycles will not be accepted, of course the use of cycles is easier and facilitates the work but the topics seek to complicate the programs :(

Comment: The for loops are just to print the result, the streams do the actual work. Anyway, I'm not sure what the objective is. Using recursion for something like this is not beneficial and will crash for an array bigger than length 1000

Comment: @Mick Teacher seeks to complicate our work, this could not be used, because you are not using java list data structure, I thought that the subject could a little easier.

Comment: You mean use a list instead of array? You can use the same code for that. I just don't understand your teachers requirements, and I don't think they are teaching you to code properly. Code should do the job in the most simple and efficient way possible. Anyway, I wish you good luck

Comment: @Mick Is the use of `import java.util.List;` as an example you mentioned this `var nums = List.of( 3, 9, 7, 12, 20, 4, 11, 9, 21, 6, 8, 10 );` And, I emphasize at the end not to use repetitive cycles, however a program must be created with the characteristics exposed in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can always do something like this (but it is cumbersome).

```
int[] vals = {10,2,8}; 
int sum = 0;
sum += vals[0];
sum += vals[1];
sum += vals[2];
double avg = (double)sum/vals.length;

List<Integer> lessThan = new ArrayList<>();
if (vals[0] < avg) {
  lessThan.add(vals[0]);
}
if (vals[1] < avg) {
  lessThan.add(vals[1]);
}
if (vals[2] < avg) {
  lessThan.add(vals[2]);
}
System.out.println(lessThan); // prints 2
```

```
var nums = List.of( 3, 9, 7, 12, 20, 4, 11, 9, 21, 6, 8, 10 );

int sum = 0;
for (int v : nums) {
   sum+=v;
}
double avg = (double)sum/v.size();
```

once you have the average you can find the ones smaller as follows.

```
vars lessThan = new ArrayList<>();
for (int v : nums) {
    // store the numbers that are less than avg in the list.
}
Then print them here.
```

Comment: @WSJ The truth is, but what can we do with the instructor. Friend, how do I print the data separately: sum of the elements, the average and the smallest average.

Comment: I would suggest, if it isn't too late, to ask  the instructor to clarify what is required.  I presume an email would work.

Comment: @WSJ This `sum += vals[0];` should I add one for each element in the array?

Comment: @WSJ There is no time, at 23:59 I must upload this topic.

Comment: @WSJ In the following way I have the total sum of the elements of the array https://ideone.com/kTwVbx

Comment: @WSJ It would only be necessary to obtain the average of that sum and the lower average

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but it looks like you solved the problem.
In your code, you have the sum of elements and the average, and you don't use an explicit loop.

The only issue is having those elements who who are smaller than the average.
A possible solution may be using a dedicated recursive function from the point you finished your first recursion (pass all elements, and checking them against the average [you already have] one by one on recursion).

Maybe something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] nums = {3, 9, 7, 12, 20, 4, 11, 9, 21, 6, 8, 10};
    System.out.println(average(nums, 0, nums)); // Added "nums" again
}

public static float average(int n[], int pos, int originalElements[]){
    float resultado = (float)suma /(float)n.length;
    if(pos < n.length) {
        suma = suma + n[pos];
        average(n, pos + 1, originalElements);
        System.out.println(resultado);
    } else {
        // you will get hete only ONCE, in case pos = n.length
        // note that in this state, "resultado" contains the original array's average
        checkSmallThanAverage(resultado, 0, originalElements);
    }
    return resultado;
}

public static void checkSmallThanAverage(float resultado, int pos, int originalElements[]) {
     if(pos < originalElements.length) {
         if (originalElements[pos] < resultado) {
             System.out.println("element " + originalElements[pos] + " is smaller than average");
         }
         checkSmallThanAverage(resultado, pos+1, originalElements);
     }
}
```

Comment: Could you tell me what line of code should I add to my code please?